# C++ polymorphism, overloading and inheritance

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, overloading

Given

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class A
{
public:
    virtual int a() const = 0;
    virtual int a(const int i) const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    virtual int a() const { return A::a(0); }    
};

class C : public B
{
public:
    virtual int a(const int i) const { return i; }
};


int main()
{
    C c;
    cout << c.a() << endl;
    cout << c.a(1) << endl; 
}
```

I did not tests with different compilers but i have the following errors:

```
main.cpp:31:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘C::a()’
     cout << c.a() << endl;
                 ^
main.cpp:24:17: note: candidate: virtual int C::a(int) const
     virtual int a(const int i) const { return i; }
                 ^
main.cpp:24:17: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

I do not understand really why, I was expecting that class `C` can access at `B::a()`.

It seems that is resolving the `C.a()` as `C.a(int)`. Basically the virtual method from `B` is not visible. Anyone knows why?

**EDIT**

The idea is something like: `A` as "interface", `B` as "abstract class", `C` the "concrete class"

**SOLUTION**

What i was trying to achieve is possible with `using A::a` `using B::a` and changing the `B::a()` call from `A::a(0)` to `a(0)`.

Like the example [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PWlLdq77H9SSK4qy) provided by [songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3309790/songyuanyao)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C::a` *hides* `B::a`. When the name `a` is found at the scope of class `C`, [name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) stops, further scopes including class `B` won't be checked.

> name lookup examines the scopes as described below, until it finds at least one declaration of any kind, at which time the lookup stops and no further scopes are examined.

You can add `using` to introduce `B::a` into `C`'s scope.

```
class C : public B
{
public:
    using B::a;
    virtual int a(const int i) const { return i; }
};
```

Comment: thanks. That is almost there, now the problem has moved to `B`: 

`In function B::a() const':undefined reference to A::a(int) const'.`

Comment: @Raffaello That's because `A::a` is not defined.

Comment: Yes but shouldn't  keep `B` abstract? basically inheriting the "`virtual A::a() const = 0;`"

Comment: @Raffaello In `B::a()` `A::a()` is called explicitly, then `A::a()` has to be defined otherwise the invocation of `B::a()` fails.

Comment: I see.......... so this kind of "pattern" won't be possible. Ok thanks.

Comment: @Raffaello I'm not sure about your intent, maybe you want to change the explicti call `A::a(0);` to `a(0);`? Then `C::a` would be called at last, as [this example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PWlLdq77H9SSK4qy).